# Creating a generic proxy function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I want to create a generic proxy function like this:

```
type Callback<F extends (...args: any) => any> = F extends (...args: infer P) => infer R 
? (
    P extends [] ? (onComplete?: (result: R) => void) => void : (parameters: P, onComplete?: (result: R) => void) => void
)
: never;

function  createCallback<P extends unknown[], R, F extends (...args: P) => R>(func: F): Callback<F> {
    return (parameters?: P | ((result: R) => void), onComplete?: (result: R) => void ): void => {
        if (Array.isArray(parameters)) {
            R result = func(...parameters);
            if (onComplete) {
                onComplete(result);
            }
        } else if (typeof parameters === "function") {
            R result = func();
            parameters(result);
        }
    }
}
```

If the passed function accepts some parameters, then the returned function should have a signature (parameters: [<tuple of function parameters], optional onComplete callback).
If the passed function does not accept any parameters, then the returned function should have a signature with a single optional onComplete callback.

Is it possible to do this in TypeScript? The above code won't compile with the error message saying the returned function is not assignable to type Callback.

Comment: please share example without wyntax errors. `R result = func(...parameters)` - is not allowed syntax

Answer (score 1):

If you're confident that `createCallback` does what it's supposed to, it's reasonable to do
`return (...) as any as Callback<F>`

Alternatively, this makes the compiler happy ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ndjH6BCgAGooLwTIaTWbGLcLQ9qHwAPTx-CMRhORhho2m833CjUUYAVgiAHZgeGs1H3rH2p1uoqoGyoBqoInk6n02XI9Gc3nC1ASxFq119XoGxrtbr9WWnL5gJ3K1RxNbbfb6U7+gAiY0QJBOdfnKczucx3P7zPT2fZj494tnZtJjRtjMm89H7uD2sjxun5+Hy+xgs3gOHRDnWo4JveKZpiYQA))

```
type Callback<F extends (...args: any) => any> = F extends (...args: infer P) => infer R
    ? (...args: PossibleArguments<P, R>) => void
    : never;

type PossibleArguments<P, R, OnComplete = (result: R) => void> =
    [] extends P
    ? ([] | [onComplete: OnComplete])
    : ([parameters: P] | [parameters: P, onComplete: OnComplete])
// or
type PossibleArguments<P, R> = [...parameters: [] extends P ? [] : [parameters: P], onComplete?: (result: R) => void]

function createCallback<P extends unknown[], R>(func: (...args: P) => R): Callback<(...args: P) => R> {
    return ((...args: PossibleArguments<P, R>): void => {
        // ...
    })
}
```

It makes the signature of callbacks ugly, but autocomplete when calling them still works

Comment: You could use [optional tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) to simplify `PossibleArguments` into `[] extends P ? [onComplete?: OnComplete] : [parameters: P, onComplete?: OnComplete]`. You could even simplify this further into `[...parameters: [] extends P ? [] : [parameters: P], onComplete?: (result: R) => void]`.

Comment: @cherryblossom That is much nicer, and it even makes hints and autocomplete look "normal". However it seems to make it impossible(?) to write the body of `createCallback` without type assertions, and at this point OP's solution might make more sense